# convert input into acronym in def function?

Tags: python

how to make a function to convert the input into the acronym in python 3.14?

I already tried this one but I think is not working

```
def acronyms():
    words = input("Please enter name: ")
    acronym = ''.join(word[0] for word in words.upper().split())
    return;
print (acronyms())
```

Comment: Python 3.4 or 3.1.4? I hope not the latter as it's ~4-5 years old.

Comment: I'd suggest updating.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have a feeling you come from the world of MATLAB. Anyway, in python, `return;` returns `None` (not to mention, the `;` is useless)

You've computed the acronym correctly - all you need to do is return it. So turn that last return statement into

```
return acronym
```

and you should be fine

Of course, you could replace your entire code with:

```
def acronyms():
    words = input("Please enter name: ").split()
    return ''.join(w[0].upper() for w in words)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shouldn't the argument be a list comprehension? You're missing brackets.

```
acronym = ''.join([word[0] for word in words.upper().split()])
```

Then return acronym:

```
return acronym
```